# Bluetooth Troubleshooting Pi 4

Tags: bluetooth

Raspberry pi 4 running Picroft image.  Trying to set up the pi as a bluetooth sink receiver as per https://github.com/nicokaiser/rpi-audio-receiver
When I try to connect, I see on my phone:

> "couldn't pair because of incorrect PIN or passkey"

bluetoothctl show gives:

> [bluetooth]# show
>
> Controller E4:5F:01:0C:B7:77 (public)     Name: picroft   Alias: picroft
> Class: 0x00040414   Powered: yes    Discoverable: yes   Pairable: yes
> UUID: Audio Sink
> (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)    UUID: Generic Attribute
> Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)    UUID: A/V Remote
> Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)     UUID: PnP
> Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)  UUID:
> A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
> UUID: Generic Access Profile
> (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0532
> Discovering: no

This *should* connect without any PIN or passkey.  Any troubleshooting advice much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I know nothing about Picroft, so I suggest you specify which sound architecture it has: ALSA, Pulse, Jack, etc.